# Table properties are not importing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, import

I am facing a problem importing a table from one server to another. I am using SQL Server 2005.

I have a db server named `QAData` and database is called `RevenueDetails` and the tablename is `tbTestRevenue`. And another db server named `ProdData`. The table `tbTestRevenue` contains `Identity` property and indexed also.

I am importing from `QAData` to `ProdData`. The import was successful. But it did not import the Identity key and index properties.

I imported using `Database name ==> right click ==> import data...`

I request you to please help me in this..

Comment: Data is not structure.  I'm not sure what you expected.

Comment: I want to import the table with index, primary key and identity properties

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard (I think so), then on the screen where you choose what table you want to copy:

1. Highlight the table that you're copying from the list
2. Click the "Edit Mappings..." button
3. Check the box for "Enable identity insert"
4. Click "Ok"
5. Proceed with any other changes you need to do